# Is there a simple LINQ method to sort a list by Month?

Tags: c#, linq

Pretend we have a simple model like this, where one column is "Month" as a three-letter string.

```
public class SampleModel
{            
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

If we wanted to sort that model by Month, A LINQ statement like

> query.OrderBy(m =>m.Month)

would produce the following alphabetical sort because `Month` is a string.

Is there a simple way to sort `Month` chronologically?

[image: Sample table]

Comment: This is a fantastic reason not to store date data as an incomplete token date string.

Comment: Except that this is what I was given and what I am expected to work with. Reality trumps ideals every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it by storing the data in a lookup table/dictionary, or an enum for that matter. This works provided you are using LINQ to Objects, not any fancy expression based LINQ.

```
Dictionary<string, int> months = new Dictionary<string, int>();
months.Add("Jan", 0);
// and so on

query.OrderBy(m => months[m.Month]);
```

This solution works well for other types of data, not just months.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. So if I wanted to do a chronological sequence that starts on a month other than January (e.g., August), I could do an August to July sort this way?

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge you could control it anyway you want.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because its versatility.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the `Month` part to `DateTime` and then use `OrderBy` like:

```
var orderedCollection = list.OrderBy(r => 
                   DateTime.ParseExact(r.Month, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

*With parsing like this, the day,year part will be selected to current date. Although that will be irrelevant for your sort*

Comment: Very simple in cases where I want to do chronological sorting starting in January. +1